# Растягивающийся поиск

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript, css

Здравствуйте, хотел спросить, как сделать раздвигающийся поиск как здесь:  http://vremenno.net/misc/

Comment: Не понимаю, почему в тегах `php`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("input#search").animate({"width":"80%"},200);//200миллисекунд на растягивание
$("#divWithOtherButtons").hide(200);
```

обошлось без тяжелого UI

Comment: Точно, а я думал что для красивой анимации без него никуда)

Answer (score 5):

Подключаете jquery-ui и по клику на элемент увеличиваете его ширину, сам элемент выравниваете по правому краю.

**Дополнено.**

Вот рабочий пример. Верстка:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="search"/>
```

CSS:

```
#search{border: 1px solid #888888; width: 250px; float: right;}
```

Скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").focusin(function(){
        $(this).animate({width: 500}, "slow");
    });
    $("#search").focusout(function(){
        $(this).animate({width: 250}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: я незнаю как сделать так чтобы растягивалось плавно. 
если я увеличиваю ширину то при нажатий  резко растягивается

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Тоже самое, только CSS3 методом

```
#search{
 width: 250px;
 -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
 transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
}

#search:focus {
 width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: > Тоже самое, только CSS3 методом...

Не совсем. А именно, этот вариант, увы, но не кроссбраузерный.

Comment: @Deonis - в вопросе не уточняется - нуда кроссбраузерность или нет.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, достаточно того, что ТС показал ссылку на вариант, который бы хотел видеть у себя. Если предположить, что он пользуется ослом (даже девятой версии), то использую вариант с CSS3, такого результата он не увидит.

P.S. Разогрел вас Yura Ivanov на вопросе с [Sublime Text 2]( http://hashcode.ru/questions/125228#125231) :D

Comment: @Deonis - скорее наоборот. К тому-же это не претензия, а уточнение.